# TypeError starting tkinter python script from bash...called within Python

Tags: python, bash, init

I have a function to call a bash script to restart the main python script. When I launch the bash script on it's own it works fine. When I call it within python it shoots out an error.

Here's how I call the bash script

```
def restartApp(self):
    sleep(1)
    rc= subprocess.call("./restart.sh", shell=True) 
    root.destroy()
```

This is the error:

```
 File "./Cataloger3000.py", line 236, in <module>
 App = App(root)
 File "./Cataloger3000.py", line 103, in __init__
  self.name_list_o= apply(OptionMenu, (root, self.variable) + tuple(item_list))
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)
```

The bash script in question is simple.

```
 #!/bin/bash
sudo ./Cataloguer3000.py
```

And the beginning where the init actually is looks like this:

```
def __init__(self,root):



    Frame.__init__(self, root, bg="white")   
    #self.initUI()
    self.master = root       
    #self.initUI()
    frame = Frame(root)   
    frame.pack()
```

Also the line the error points to is an OptionMenu component in my GUI. The item_list is the only variable that could be causing trouble.

```
    self.variable = StringVar()
    item_list = self.getList()
```

And this is what getList looks like:

```
def getList(self):
    item_list=[]
    text_file = open('catalog.txt','r')
    lines = text_file.read()
    lines = lines.split(',')
    list= lines[0::2]
    qu= lines[1::2]
    print list
    length = len(list)
    n=0
    try:
        while(n<=length):

            name = list[n]
            quan= qu[n]

            display= name + ' ' + quan
            print(display)
            item_list.append(display)

            n=n+1

    except IndexError:
        pass


    return item_list
```

I feel like this is super obvious but I'm running in circles.

Comment: When it fails, is `item_list` empty?

Comment: Nope, I had considered that and put an arbitrary list after the function is called, same error.

Comment: If you can reproduce the error with a static list of data, please create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to reproduce your results.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll have it posted later today.

Comment: I ended up just finding a way to update the OptionMenu directly. A solution is no longer necessary.